# Postgresql/Docker - password authentication failed for user "user"

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have set database with postgresql and docker, now when I want to access to my database I have this connection error saying password authentication failed for user "user". I already search answers but none helped me. Btw, I am new to this so I may have missed something.
Here my docker-compose.yaml (which I'm not sure is configured correctly) :

```
version: "3"

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: main
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: main
      POSTGRES_DB: main
    ports: [5432]

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db_app
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret_password
      POSTGRES_USER: symfony
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

I also saw that it may be config in pg_hba file but don't know where it is located.

Any help ?

Comment: You probably need to post your symfony database config file too.

Comment: You cannot have multiple compose services use the same key (`database` in this case)

Comment: Please share more details. I sthis a Docker problem, a PostgreSQL problem, or a Symfony problem? I assume that not all of these techniques are really related to your question. Can you access the database on any other way, but not from Symfony?

Comment: inside the container:

find / -name pg_hba.conf

Comment: and in the pg_hba.conf is -> host   all     all    your_public_ip/32   md5, save and restart  the container

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two `database` services names? And which password do you use?

If you use `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: main` don't work because your password overwrite by the second `database` service.

```sh
docker-compose config
```

Output:

```sh
services:
  database:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db_app
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret_password
      POSTGRES_USER: symfony
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: db-data
      target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volume: {}
networks:
  default:
    name: tmp_default
volumes:
  db-data:
    name: tmp_db-data
```

If you connect with `secret_password` it's work.

Please remove one of the services and make sure you have a unique name for each service.

Comment: Thank you I removed the first service and edit my file as the `docker compose config` output but it still doesn't work